# how to rewrite url's as proper SEO url in kohana 3.2?

Tags: .htaccess, url, bootstrapping, kohana-3.2

I'm using kohana3.2. i want to rewrite the url's in t o proper SEO url's. For ex,
my url is now http://samplesite.com/user/register/ . but i want my url as http://samplesite.com/register.html.

In 2.3.4 version of kohana , in routes file (application/config/routes.php) we will do the changes ..

How to do it in kohana 3.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the answer you are looking for but Kohana is setup to use pretty urls so what you are trying to do, as already stated, is going backwards but you can setup a specific route like so:

```
Route::set('seo', '<controller>/<action>.html')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'page',
        'action'     => 'index'
    ));
```

You would still need to specify the controller and action but at least you can have the .html on the end. In the case of this route, you have to use http://domain.com/user/register.html.

If you want to use one route per url, you can also use:

```
Route::set('seo', 'register.html')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'user',
        'action'     => 'register'
    ));
```

Comment: The first route would need to go BEFORE the default route Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>))).

The second route would need to go BEFORE the first route AND the default route. The default route should always be last. The first one found that satisfies the search pattern is used.

Answer (score 0):

Proper SEO?  That seems like you're going in the wrong direction.

But...if you really want to do this...add a route in your bootstrap.php:

```
Route::set('funny_seo', '<action>.html')
    ->defaults(array(
          'controller' => 'user',
));
```

Comment: proper SEO in the sense format of url's . As i said in my question like my url is http://samplesite.com/user/register/ . But i need like http://samplesite.com/register.html .. any help??

Comment: Why wouldn't the solution I proposed work?  It would change user/register to just the action which is register.

Comment: yes, i have tried your solution. but its not working for me. Is there any other changes need to be done?

Comment: Can you give me an error or maybe some information on what is not working with the new solution?